# What's the correct way of feedback the user when a record is deleted from the store (using api)?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm using a `Store` that have a proxy with `api` declared. I can handle exceptions with the `exception listener`, but how can I send a message to the user when a record is deleted with success?

My store looks like:

```
Ext.define('ContatosApp.store.PsContatosStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'ContatosApp.model.PsContatosModel'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            autoSync: true,
            model: 'ContatosApp.model.PsContatosModel',
            storeId: 'MyJsonStore',
            pageSize: 15,
            trailingBufferZone: 20,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                api: {
                    read: 'contact/list',
                    create: 'contact/save',
                    update: 'contact/update',
                    destroy: 'contact/delete'
                },
                directionParam: 'order',
                limitParam: 'max',
                startParam: 'offset',
                url: '',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'contatos'
                },
                writer: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: ''
                },
                listeners: {
                    exception: {
                        fn: me.onAjaxException,
                        scope: me
                    }
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    },

    onAjaxException: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
        var data = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title: 'Error',
            msg: data.message,
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
        });
    }

});
```

And my delete button handler is:

```
var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#MyGridPanel');
var selection = grid[0].getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
if (selection) {
  Ext.getStore('PsContatosStore').remove(selection);
}
```

Also, if I delete the record from the store, but the ajax call returns with error, I need to reload the grid to show the record again, or is there some better way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this globally for all ajax calls using [requestcomplete](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-event-requestcomplete).

For a particular proxy, you can use the [afterRequest](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-method-afterRequest):

```
        proxy: {

            ...

            listeners: {
                exception: {
                    fn: me.onAjaxException,
                    scope: me
                }
            afterRequest: function( aRequest, aSuccess ) {
                console.log( aSuccess );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hmmm, I added `afterRequest`, but `console.log()` doesn't show anything. I put an alert, and it seems that this isn't fired.

Comment: Definitely works for me. Are you sure the server is called and indeed returns success?

Comment: Using afterRequest this way is hardly a hack. In fact, it's actually the way in which is was intended to be used. From the docs: "This is a template method. a hook into the functionality of this class. Feel free to override it in child classes." http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-method-afterRequest

Comment: Thanks for that existdissolve. It's just that for 4.1 this method is undocumented. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, I ended up using the global requestcomplete + rejectChanges() in the onAjaxException. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the docs for [sync()](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-sync). You can pass success and failure callbacks which will fire when either a successful response is received from the server, or an error.

As far as putting the record back in the grid, check ou the [rejectChanges()](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-rejectChanges) method of the store. I typically call this in my failure callback.

Comment: Thanks, `sync()` works. The problem is that I cannot access the ajax response in this case.